Getting IntelliJ to generate Java Sources from Proto files
On my Mac I have libprotoc 27.3 (Protocol Buffers (Protobuf)) installed locally and I am trying to get it to "play nice" with my Java 17 app inside of IntelliJ. My Java app has the following high-level directory structure:
myapp/
    src/
        main/
            java/
            proto/
            resources/

Inside the src/main/proto/ directory is a single file called dostuff.proto and it looks like this:
syntax = "proto3";

package stuffdoer;
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.me.myapp.dostuff.stuffdoer";

message DoStuffRequest{
  bytes image = 1;
}

message DoStuffResponse{
  string stuff_image = 1;
}

service DoStuffDetection{
  rpc GetStuffToDo(DoStuffRequest) returns (DoStuffResponse) {}
}

I believe the idea is that I need to run this tool to generate Java source code that can then be used in other areas of this project. Sure enough, I see that there are Java source files that seem to expect Java code generated by this file. One example is in a Java source file called DoStuffClient that declares the following import statements:
package com.me.myapp.dostuff.stuffdoer.client;

import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.me.myapp.dostuff.stuffdoer.DoStuffGrpc;
import com.me.myapp.dostuff.stuffdoer.DoStuffRequest;
import io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException;

...

In IntelliJ, I am getting compiler errors because I have not explicitly ran Google Protocol Buffers to read this dostuff.proto and generate the DoStuffGrpc and DoStuffRequest Java sources.
When I run the Maven build locally and run the app on my local machine, it starts up and I am able to manually test the code in the DoStuffClient and verify it works just fine. So I believe Maven is correctly generating the Java sources (defined in dostuff.proto) and making them available to the Java runtime.
However it is annoying to be getting the compiler errors in IntelliJ. What can I do to invoke Google Protocol Buffers from inside IntelliJ so that it generates the Java sources (defined in dostuff.proto) and makes them available to the compile-time path, so that I stop seeing compiler errors when I'm writing code in IntelliJ?
What are the exact steps to take to get IntelliJ generating Java sources from my .proto files and then getting it to link them to the compile-time path so that other source files in the opened project can "see" them?

Use a maven plugin or gradle plugin instead. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java

But I am using the Maven plugin (as stated in the question!) and it builds fine. I don't think the Maven plugin would generate the code for me inside of IntelliJ, right?

Your belief is wrong. Set the plugin up on your project pom file, IJ will execute it when running the build.

OK then that's what I'm missing: how to set the plugin up on my project POM. If you are able to answer that with succinct steps, I'll happily give you the green check! Otherwise I'll wait for someone else to answer. Thanks again!

So as discussed on the comments you will need to set up the protobuf generator plugin on your pom.xml file. Since there are no details whatsoever of your pom file I will add the basic steps that will likely help you set yours up.
Make sure you have the dependencies for the protobuf java in your <dependencies> section: from the documentation
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>1.66.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
  <version>1.66.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
  <version>1.66.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.53</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Then in the build section add the plugin for the protobuf, this code is directly from the plugin documentation I just added the path of your proto files to the configuration
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/proto</protoSourceRoot>
        <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.25.3:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.66.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

I would recommend looking through the documentation for any specifics.

Thanks, what would be the Maven CLI command to generate the sources? I just tried and mvn clean test does not appear generate them.

Yes, you can find more information on it here: https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/ and here (linked on the previous one) https://protobuf.dev/reference/java/java-generated/

Also you probably want to add the install goal on your maven command as well.

So if you'd like it to play nice, you have to generate the files while you're working.
From your resources folder in terminal (which you can do from a terminal inside intellij), you will need to run the command to generate the java code from the proto:
protoc --java_out="../java" --proto_path=./ *.proto
Note: You may want to set up a script that removes any proto files, and then recreates the protos if you're going to be making additions/changes to the proto as time goes on. It's easier than doing it manually everytime.
Since it's inside the same project, you should be able to run a mvn clean install to get it to try to make the connections for you.
If it does not automatically add the source files, you can add them by going into your settings -> modules -> sources (I believe), and adding the source folder.
